# How do I completely disable microphone on a Logitech webcam?

Tags: audio, microphone, webcam

I've been running into an issue on Google Meet where every time my computer goes to sleep, it switches the default microphone from my built-in MacBook Pro microphone to my Logitech BRIO microphone.

This has been causing plenty of issues during meetings. Sometimes my Mac doesn't even have to fall asleep first. *Randomly it will switch the microphone from my default to the Logitech microphone*. A Google search has been no help with this one and it's driving me nuts.

The only thing I can think of would be permanently disabling the Logitech mic. I've looked through my Chrome settings and System Preferences on my computer, but to no avail.

Any insights?

Comment: An interesting [physical hack](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6795412) involving a small length of tape.